# Why isn't this crontab job running

Tags: cron

I have a cron job that runs every minute on an Ubuntu 12.04 box

```
$sudo crontab -e
* * * * * mylogin /pathto/file.sh > /log/filelog
```

If I run `file.sh`, the bash script does some stuff and echos out `runs`:

```
$ ./file.sh 
runs
```

If I check the log of cron tab it shows that the job is running:

```
Jul 10 12:41:01 localhost CRON[1811]: (root) CMD (mylogin /pathto/file.sh > /log/filelog)
Jul 10 12:41:01 localhost CRON[1810]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jul 10 12:42:01 localhost CRON[1813]: (root) CMD (mylogin /pathto/file.sh > /log/filelog)
```

However, the script is not running. It is not doing it's work and not echoing `runs` to `/log/filelog`.

```
$cat /log/filelog  #shows nothing
```

What other steps can I take to debug this problem?

Comment: "info (No MTA installed, discarding output)" ... was probably the error message that'd explain why your script isn't running. You could install one (possibly a very trivial one, or even just a /usr/sbin/sendmail script...)

Comment: "mylogin" what is this ?i assume if you remove this it will be executed .. and it is always better to do log inside the script and cron entries to redirect to /dev/nul

Comment: @klerk mylogin is my username! just not posting that online. I did not know that about logging and will do so in the future. But problem still remains

Comment: you dont need username! if you edit crontab with some user it is writen in /var/spool/cron/<username> if script is ok it will work without mylogin!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specifying a username like `mylogin` is for the `/etc/crontab` file. With your command `sudo crontab -e` you are actually editing `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` and you should not specify a username in such a file, only in `/etc/crontab`.

If you have to run the command as user `mylogin` you have to put the line in `/etc/crontab` (and edit this with `root` privileges), or just put it in the `mylogin` user's crontab.

From `man 5 crontab`:

```
EXAMPLE SYSTEM CRON FILE
    The following lists the content of a regular system-wide crontab  file.
    Unlinke  a user's crontab, this file has the username field, as used by
    /etc/crontab.
```