# CronTab is not working in Ubuntu for image compression job : "/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory"

Tags: bash, cron

I am trying to set up a cronjob to execute the following script. The function of the script is to find and compress png and jpg files in a WordPress directory.

```
    #!/bin/bash
echo `date` >> /root/optipng.log
find /home/ghost/wp-content/uploads -mtime -2 -iname '*.png' -print0 | \
 xargs -0 optipng -o7 -log /root/optipng.log -preserve
echo `date` >> /root/jpegoptim.log
find /home/ghost/wp-content/uploads  -mtime -2 -iname '*.jpg' -print0 | \
 xargs -0 jpegoptim --max=90 --preserve --totals >> /root/jpegoptim.log
```

So I created a file "**optimize.sh**" in /usr/local directory 
and ran "**crontab -e**" and added the following command:

```
00 10 * * *  root  /usr/local/optimize.sh
```

This is supposed to run the image optimization every day at 10:00 hours but it is not working in this case, I even tried to create a log file by modifying the above command as:

```
00 10 * * *  root  /usr/local/optimize.sh &>/var/log/cron.log
```

The log file is empty and cron job is not running. I did try the other methods mentioned in Stack Overflow, none of them seemed to work. I am also listing some other tutorials which I turned for help:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/28995/setup-cron-weekly-backup

http://seravo.fi/2013/tips-to-optimize-images-for-faster-loading-websites

Can someone please point out where the mistake is? :)

PS- I gave 700 permission to the file /usr/local/optimize.sh and I tried running the file directly via ssh and it returns the following error:

```
/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Here is a picture of the exact way the commands are written using nano editor:
[image: there are no spaces in the script.]

This question is different from others in Stack Overflow like [Why isn't this crontab job running](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143825/why-isnt-this-crontab-job-running) in the sense that the error was not in the way cron file was written, but there were some hidden spaces in the file optimize.sh.

Comment: Run your command from the commandline and make sure it works. Then make sure that all programs used in the script are in the limited path provided by the cron environment. Make sure you edit your files with an editor that doesn't put CR before newlines. Don't mix `/etc/crontab` and `crontab -e` syntax.

Comment: Also please rewrite your question as a single, coherent, whole. This means no sections introduced with **EDIT** or **UPDATE** or similar. The system keeps track of your edits and we can see what changes have been made, in case we don't want to re-read the whole. It is important that future visitors find a concise and readable question, instead of a hodgepodge of add-on afterthoughts. (I didn't see your first version, so why do you waste my time, by having me read that there was a small mistake and that the question is now correct?)

Comment: The proposed answer by @roaima should solve the problem : `/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter` through the  `dos2unix` tool. The linked answer doesn't solve the main problem.

Comment: That `^M` shows everything, you have a crlf ending in your script. However, your system should be able to handle this, it is another story, why it can't. Find that script and use the `dos2unix` command  (available in package `tofrodos`) to fix its line endings. I think your question is not a dupe.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of problems remaining:

1. You created the fine on a Windows machine and copied it to the server. Unless you have a "text transfer" mode this leaves CR/LF endings for each line. As suggested by others run `dos2unix` on the file to fix this.
2. Remove the leading spaces from the #! line, as already suggested by others.
3. Do not write to /var/log/cron.log. That is a system log file and you should not be writing to it.
4. Don't use `chmod -R 777` to make a single file executable. Instead use `chmod 755` or even better just `chmod a+x`.
5. Also pointed out by others, when you use `crontab -e` the system know who you are, so the `crontab` format must not include the username.
6. Instead of `` echo `date` `` consider simply `date`.

Answer (score 0):

Your cron line format is wrong. Here is an example:

```
0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
```

i.e. don't name the user, you only put the user name in if you are adding lines to /etc/crontab, but if you are using `crontab -e` then you are adding to the current user's crontab file.

Comment: I tried that version as well. It did not work, it returned empty log files and did not run the cron job

Comment: @RahulRamesh I guess your file optimize.sh has execute permission for your user? does it run ok from command line? try adding a line at the end `echo optimize.sh completed` then you will know for sure

Comment: @RahulRamesh so from what you just replied to DevNull I think you need `chmod +x /usr/local/optimize.sh`

Comment: @RahulRamesh: ^M in the error message suggests to me that there is some Windows line-formatting in your optimize.sh file? Or maybe in your copy/pasting to here? First thing is to forget about crontab until you have your script working at command line. I suggest you try editing it locally (e.g. with nano) and take out any '^M' characters at ends of lines (if there are such).

Comment: @RahulRamesh: I still think the error message you are seeing means you must have some Windows line-formatting that for some reason is not showing in the screen shot. If you don't have dos2unix as suggested by DevNull then you can achieve the same by: `sed -i 's/\r$//' /usr/local/optimize.sh`

Comment: Ohh I just tried the command you suggested, it still shows the error, actually I did not copy paste from windows, I typed it inside the nano editor within SSH

Comment: strange! try running nano with -N option which might show up ^M character i.e. `nano -N /usr/local/optimize.sh`

Are there any extra spaces or characters after /bin/bash in your file?

Answer (score 0):

Update (from our chat):

Your question shows spaces at the beginning of `#!/bin/bash` please make sure that none exist. Also if you did any windows to linux copying try running the following command, to remove any `^M` characters and try running the script again:

```
    sed -i s/{ctrl+v}{ctrl+m}// /usr/local/optimize.sh
```

Or if you have `dos2unix` run:

```
    dos2unix /usr/local/optimize.sh
```

---

You are running the job 10am every Friday.

[The command sh will execute at 10:00am Fridays in every month.](http://cronchecker.net/check?utf8=%E2%9C%93&statement=00+10+*+*+5+sh&button=)

What I think you want is:

```
00 10 * * *  /usr/local/optimize.sh > /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake that happened when i rewrote my commands here. I corrected my question. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @RahulRamesh, ok well that helps -- Does your script run if you execute it? What happens when you do `/usr/local/optimize.sh`? Does anything print out to the terminal? What are the file permissions?

Comment: it is saying "**permission denied**" so i performed the chown command for the root user (which is my default user) and still it is saying "**permission denied**"

Comment: Now after I gave it chmod -R 777 permission for the file /usr/local/optimize.sh, the command returns "** /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory**"

Comment: Please update your question with the output from `ls -l /usr/local/optimize.sh`. You might be missing executable permissions. `chmod 700 /usr/local/optimize.sh` if you are running this only as root.

Comment: @RahulRamesh Your question shows spaces at the beginning of `#!/bin/bash` please make sure that none exist. Also if you did any windows to linux copying try running `sed -i s/{ctrl+v}{ctrl+m}// /usr/local/optimize.sh` to remove any `^M` characters and try running the script again. Or if you have `dos2unix` run `dos2unix /usr/local/optimize.sh`

Comment: There are no spaces. I posted a screenshot of the original file in my question.

Comment: @RahulRamesh did the `dos2unix` not work? (I updated my answer from our chat)